# Flink IngestionTime Implementation While Migrating From 1.4.2 to 1.14.2

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

We have stream processing pipeline to ingest Kafka messages. And we were using Flink v1.4.2. and now planning to migrate to 1.14.2.

Timestamps are based on ingest-time. As        env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.IngestionTime) is depcreated since 1.12 , how to set this ??

Which watermark strategy should be used ?

timeWinow() is also deprecated. I Couldn't find way to use: window(SlidingIngestionTimeWindows.of()) only SlidingProcessingTimeWindows/SlidingEventTimeWindows available.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm curious to understand why you aren't upgrading to 1.14.6 instead, in order to take advantage of more bug fixes. Did we get something wrong after 1.14.2?

Comment: actually the migration is already done and it was decided to use 1.14.2 long back. I m trying to replace the deprecated classes to get better performance . Like kafkaFlinkProducer with KafkaSink, kafkaFlinkConsumer with KafkaSource, timeWindow, TimeCharacteristic.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to use a watermark strategy like this one

```java
WatermarkStrategy<Event> wmStrategy =
    WatermarkStrategy
        .<Event>forMonotonousTimestamps()
        .withTimestampAssigner((event, timestamp) -> System.currentTimeMillis());
```

in combination with SlidingEventTimeWindows.

Comment: Thanks David!

Curious to know how the system time will work with Event-time based sliding window ? 

Please share more details it will be really helpful.

Comment: The watermark strategy I gave as an example is exactly what ingestion time did before, under the hood. The ingestion time TimeCharacteristic was the same as event time, but with an ascending timestamps watermark generator and a timestamp assigner that used System.currentTimeMillis for the timestamps.